# AWS ALB's Port based routing to ECS tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have two tasks in AWS ECS.
A. is a default target, mysite.com
B. forwarding rule , path based "/api/*"

I want to also forward to task B container when the request has a separate port specified like
mysite.com:12345

Is it possible?

I tried to add a new listener beyond 443 and 80 but it shows a warning that it's not reachable because the security group is not allowing it(and I don't think I can change the security group).

Comment: You can update security group to allow 12345 port and create a new rule it will forward to task B.

Comment: Right so even if I allow port 12345,  I have a default target mysite.com goes to task A. How would I then add a rule that differentiates the default target with port 443 that goes to A and mysite.com:12345 that should go to task B. Because it not enough to open port 12345 , it will just go by default to task A

Answer (score 1):

If you want requests to reach your load balancer on that port, at least one security group on the load balancer must allow inbound traffic on that port. You can either edit an existing SG attached to the load balancer, or add a new SG to the load balancer.